# FatalErrorException in Articles.php line 22: Call to undefined method Carbon\Carbon::createFormFormat()

Tags: laravel

I am getting error on this code so I start it from blade, then controller then modle kindly give me solution why this problem happened.

blade:

```
@extends ('lay')
@section('content')

<h1>Write a New Article</h1>
<hr>

{!!Form::open(['url'=>'articles'])!!}

<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('title','Title:')!!}
{!!Form::text('title','',['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('body','Body:')!!}
{!!Form::textarea('body','',['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

</div>

<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('published_at','Published on:')!!}
{!!Form::input('date','published_at',date('Y-m-d'),['class'=>'form-control'])!!}

</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::submit('Add Article',['class'=>'btn btn-primary form-control','name'=>'submit'])!!}
</div>

{!!Form::close()!!}

@stop
```

controller: this is my controller of the program all this is made in laravel

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Articles;
use Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ArticlesController extends Controller {

public function index()
{

/*$art=[
'title'=>'ashwani',
'body'=>'rathi',
'published_at'=>'Carbon\Carbon::now()'
];

Articles::create($art);*/
$articles=Articles::latest()->get();

return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));

}

public function show($id)
{

$article=Articles::findorFail($id);
return view('articles.show',compact('article'));

}

public function create(){

    return view('articles.create');
}
public function store()
{


//$input=Request::all();
//$input['published_at']=Carbon::now();

//Articles::create($input);
Articles::create(Request::all());
return redirect('articles');
}
}
```

model: this is model where i using date and its not working

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Articles extends Model {
    protected $fillable= [ 'title', 'body', 'published_at' ];

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
    {  
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFormFormat('Y-m-d|', $date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is stemming from a small typo.

You have put `createFormFormat`, where you have spelt `Form` instead of `From`.

You just need to correct this in your function:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
}
```

Comment: will you please suggest me any tutorial or where laravel teaches me more in detail, coz here are some points where i am not cleared in laracast, like from wher this $date is coming, i am new in php and laravel

Comment: @AshwaniRathi I can have a look for you, but did the above work for you?

Comment: @AshwaniRathi the function is just a model mutator. You can read more about these here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: do u have any fb, twitter or any thing such so i can ask u question frequently?

Comment: @AshwaniRathi great, given that can you accept the answer and upvote it if you can?
As for contacting me, just do it through chat one here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57538

Comment: plz tell from where this $date is coming?

Comment: @James linked to the Laravel accessors & mutators documentation which explains how mutators work (and that method is a mutator). Also if you want to learn Laravel I strongly suggest you watch the [**Laravel From Scratch**](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch) series on Laracasts which explains in detail how Laravel and its different components work.

Comment: For your particular case you can watch the [**Dates, Mutators and Scopes**](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/11) episode from Laracasts which explains exactly how a date mutator works.

Comment: i am learnig it from https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/11 is'nt not ok

Comment: If you read the **Defining a mutator** section from the link @James posted in the comments, you will see it reads: _"The mutator **will receive the value that is being set on the attribute**, allowing you to manipulate the value and set the manipulated value on the Eloquent model's internal $attributes property."_. That means that `$date` is automatically passed by Eloquent and it contains the value that you're assigning to the `published_at` attribute of your model. So when you do `$article->published_at = 'some date'` the `$date` variable will contain `some date`.

Comment: i am learning laravel from https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals is it ok or i have to go with scratch which is best for beginer?

Comment: Laravel 5 fundamentals is for Laravel 5.0 released in 2015. You should instead learn about the current version which is Laravel 5.2 and which is explained in [Laravel From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch).

Comment: ok, i hadnt tried for any mvc before and know normal php so is it ok to start with scratch without 5.0 means basic

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 public function getPublishedAtAttribute($date){
        return Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date){
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
    }
```

in place of

```
 public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date){
        //$this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFormFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
         return $this->attributes['published_at']->format('Y-m-d');
     }
```